# Are there any relevant philosophers who’ve touched on the points raised?

Tags: consciousness, reality

Below is a summary of my thoughts on reality and human consciousness:

Man I watched Michio Kaku talk about quantum mechanics/spirituality and finished reading that declassified CIA document about Gateway Experience. I remember reading The Alchemist and it mentioned that if you want something so much, the universe does everything it can to give it to you. If all reality is just frequencies—waves—what’s not to say acting on the human will affects these frequencies in a way that aligns the universe to exact your desires?

Infinite universes can exist due to infinite possibilities, yet our conscious awareness is only locked into one universe at a time due to the limitations of our third dimensional physical bodies locked into a single universe.

Our bodies act as antennae receiving our consciousness, which is itself, an amalgamation of different frequencies (visual, auditory, etc) under a manifold of a priori principles facilitated by our physical anatomy.

But what if our will, which wants something so much, ends up with our conscious awareness aligning itself with the reality we desire so much, similar to when you change radio stations, making possible the universe containing your dreams?

Answer (score 1):

> "A man can do as he wills, but not will as he wills." *-Schopenhauer*

You may want something, but will you want to be the person who receives it?

You might like to read about [Quantum Suicide & Quantum Immortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_immortality).

In the Buddhist tradition, they seek liberation through non-attachment, through not being conditioned by our desires and attachments. The approach of Buddhist esoteric tantra is to invert that, to use our desires as tools for liberation. There is a commonality between these: Know Thyself, will help either with the path of non-attachment or attachment.

I relate this to wisdom, being skillful at solving dilemmas by acting from the integrated centre of your concerns, in this answer: [Wisdom and John Vervaeke's awakening from the meaning crises?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82325/wisdom-and-john-vervaekes-awakening-from-the-meaning-crises/82333#82333)

Who wants something? Will you still be the person that wanted it, after doing the work to get it? That is the domain for the exercise of wisdom. To know who you really are, is to know what you really need. Perhaps the different 'frequencies' are the different selves we put out into the world/s. And the Big Insight, is to find what all our parallel selves can agree on, to integrate and reconcile, to find the integrated centre of who we are, and wish to be.

We need an ethics for the multiverse, that aims towards the best of all possible worlds.