# How not to lose myself while aiming high?

Tags: values

Considering the rapidly transforming environment and pressure from society, how to achieve my own goals without losing an attachment to the core values?

Comment: Reading philosophy is already not a bad start, I think

Comment: What are your goals? Which core values? This question needs a lot more details before it would be answerable, but I'm also not convinced that it's on topic here. It sounds more like a question about generally living life and weighing up different priorities, with an unclear link to philosophy.

Comment: @NotThatGuy. I'm not so sure. It seems to me to be very close to the question of 'How do I live a good life?', a classic philosophical question.

Comment: @Futilitarian A lot can and has been said in philosophy about the goal of life and which values to have, but the question doesn't seem to be asking about that. If you already have some goals and values in mind, the problem is more of an implementation detail.

Comment: @NotThatGuy. Yeah... I guess I see that 'implementation' as key to the question of _how_ to live a good life... ie. How to balance values against desires and demands.. It's a massive subject though, which is why I deleted my answer which was shallow and didn't point to relevant schools of thought.

Comment: By cultivating wisdom, as discussed here: 'Wisdom and John Vervaeke's awakening from the meaning crises?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82325/wisdom-and-john-vervaekes-awakening-from-the-meaning-crises/82333#82333

Answer (score 1):

I'll share what works for me, so you are free to take my words with a grain of salt.

I try to act using an ethic system that I have carefully curated over the years from reading and learning about different political and moral philosophies.

This helps me decide things and commit to them, it also makes me avoid second-guessing all the time, because I can safely look back at my decisions and understand why I made them.

Being able to make conscious decisions like that gives me a sense of stability, and that's important when things are not going your way.

## Aiming high or low?

I work in a per-project basis, so, although I have high expectations of my future (that keeps me focused on progressing), my goals and objectives are containerized, this way, I can relieve the everyday stress of feeling accomplished. That is what works **for me**, but you may be completely different.

Having big objectives may motivate you, but it also may stress you out. Having small ones may make you feel hopeless, or it may make your objectives more digestible.

Finding out your best solution will require some investigating, but with some trial and error, you'll get there rather fast.

## Discipline

Lastly, work on your discipline.

You can do this by doing useful things that you may not want to do (e.g. go to the gym), your brain needs to know that regardless of how you feel, some things **need to get done** so "loosing yourself" can't be a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

Aiming high can be anything from different perspectives.

From…

1. the individual’s point of view
2. the people of a locality’s point of view
3. the community’s / religion’s point of view
4. the underdog’s point of view
5. the nation’s point of view
6. the humanity’s point of view (in all aspects)

Often all these aims are different. So first you have to decide if you have chosen your high goal wisely.   Then you can choose a role model and follow his/her path, whom you can follow with full confidence.

Practise the Dharma.  If you have full confidence in the words of *Rishis* – *[‘Dharmo rakshati rakshitah’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmo_Rakshati_Rakshitah)* it will give you courage /confidence in your pursuit of high goal. Patience, sincerity, perseverance, positive thinking etc., will help you achieve your high goal.

Sometimes your own goals may be of the last category.  While pursuing such high goals, you will lose your ‘constricted you’.  And when you do your activities with full dedication to humanity or as offerings to God you will not be deviated from values.

https://asitis.com/3/12.html.  I think your own goal won't fall in this category.