# Any neuroscience-informed takes on the meaning of life?

Tags: meaning-of-life

Can science tell us objectively what the meaning of life is?

Are these the fellows to unlock the mystery?: dopamine, oxytocin, cortisol, seratonin, endorphins

I'm not sure of the status of evolutionary psychology, but apparently not as 'hard' as neuroscience; perhaps too 'theory-laden'.

Are any philosophers taking neuroscience and harder forms of psychology seriously to answer the question, at least at a general level? We might need to fill in the rest with idiosyncratic narratives, but at least we're one step closer.

btw, I really believe the question can be answered. Humans are animals afterall, just very complicated. But perhaps we're just not trying hard enough, or maybe there's something human in us that doesn't really want someone to tell us a definitive answer as that might curtail our sense of freedom as it could become an obligation.

Comment: Neuro science can tell you what behavior an average human brain is wired to feel gratified about and seek to reproduce. No surprise, this behavior will be focused on you and your tribe surviving and having offspring, not because of some grand scheme but because hominid species who didn't have this drive disappeared, leaving only us. None of this will tell you that this is what _you_ should strive to do. For example a sure way to have high levels of oxytocin is masturbating all day. Not sure that's what you mean by "meaning of life".

Comment: I perceive some hostility in your reply. Science can inform us about what we should do, not just what is, in many aspects of our life. It can be as basic as wash your hands to prevent infections, or what will really make us happy in the long term through longitudinal studies, MRI responses to given stimuli, etc. Your counter-example is not even valid. 
I am not interested in playing linguistic games.

Comment: For anyone who wants to take a sympathetic approach to this question, at least intitially, it may help to know that others are taking it seriously: after a quick Google (unfortunately, no public access to the article): https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/41276/chapter-abstract/351575044?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: The literal meaning of life is whatever you're doing that prevents you from killing yourself.”
          -Albert Camus

Comment: I do enjoy Camus' stories, but let's not shift the context of the question too much :)

Comment: The meaning of life... You have to define meaning for *whom*. Meanings are like opinions or preferences, always subjective, personal.

Comment: Science cannot tell us the meaning of life in principle, and taking it seriously means not expecting it to. Its task is to establish facts, not values, it can tell us how things *are*, but not what we ought to *value and do* with our lives, which is what the meaning of life is about, see [fact–value distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact%E2%80%93value_distinction). What science *can* do is provide the means for fulfilling that meaning, for living according to our values and for achieving our goals. But only after we decide what we value and want to achieve.

Comment: You are on a bit of a sticky wicket here, because Hume's Is-Ought argument points to your question being a category error - no examination of the world can tell you how you ought to behave, you must look inward to who you are & wish to be, for that. So I would ask you, what do you think meaning *is*? What does it *do* for us? For a relevant answer to that, see 'Isn't there an inherent contradiction in creating your own meaning in life?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10064/isnt-there-an-inherent-contradiction-in-creating-your-own-meaning-in-life/72016#72016

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki: Is the meaning of pi being the ratio of circumference to diameter of a circle, subjective & personal? Aren't you proposing morality is some kind of Private Language?

Comment: You need to accept the context in which I am using the words "meaning of life" to understand what I mean. This should be obvious.

Comment: This is not is-ought. This is about another discipline informing philosophy. This happened with Hume and probably every philosophy throughout history. 
The question again is "Any neuroscience-informed takes on the meaning of life?"

Comment: @CriglCragl The meaning of life in this context refers to a teleological purpose of an individual's life. That is a religious question,  not a neuroscientific one.

Comment: Sorry if i sounded hostile, not my intention. Your reply shows you are mistaken about is and ought statements. Science can tell you the best way to reach a goal ("wash your hands to keep healthy"), but can't tell you what goal you should aim for. You say it yourself: "It can be as basic as wash your hands to prevent infections" yes, _if you set as your goal to prevent infection_. But you don't have to, and no fact can tell you what your ultimate goal should be, i.e. the meaning of life. And my exemple is valid. Wanna be happy for the rest of your life? Science tells you to overdose on heroin.

Comment: The meaning of life can be informed through neuroscience/science, like some amazing process which underlies all life, wow to that! But those never actually decide it. Even if neuroscience discovers specific processes belying human tendencies to attributing meaning to life in specific ways, it wont touch what most modern philosophers call meaning. The alternative, that science decides meaning was tried in logical empiricism, which failed. You'd need to establish a necessary connection between science and meaning, bypassing the human/mental component, which is wrong to ignore by history for one.

Comment: I would offer as meaningful, "what I would like to do if there were no obstacles, impairments or limitations in the way", what an ordinary person could hope to do with their life.

Answer (score 4):

According to "The Oxford Handbook of Meaning in Life", one can distinguish three answers to the question of whether neuroscience is relevant to meaning in life.

> - Neuro-neutral: Neuroscience is irrelevant to questions about meaning in life so it can be safely ignored.
> - Neuro-negative: Neuroscience is relevant to meaning in life only as a warning about how meaning can be distorted or destroyed by excessive attention to scientific findings about the mind.
> - Neuro-positive: Neuroscience has findings that contribute to philosophical understanding of meaning in life and to guiding people about how to have meaningful lives.

Quoting further - see [this link](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Ir9qEAAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA127&dq=the+relevance+of+neuroscience+meaning+of+life&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=the%20relevance%20of%20neuroscience%20meaning%20of%20life&f=false) for full:

> This chapter defends the neuro-positive view after critiquing the two alternatives. It shows how neuroscience helps to answer questions about the meaning of meaningfulness, the characteristics of meaningful lives, the objectivity of life’s meaning, strategies for obtaining meaning, and changes in life’s meaning that occur with aging.

Comment: Good find. Rather than just providing a link though, and the short para you've provided, a good answer would include examples of '_how neuroscience helps to answer questions, about the meaning of meaningfulness, the characteristics of meaningful lives, the objectivity of life’s meaning, strategies for obtaining meaning, and changes in life’s meaning that occur with aging_'.

Comment: Should this be an answer or an extension to the question? If the OP answers a question themselves, often it means they found the correct answer.

Comment: "*There is nothing good or bad, but thinking* makes *it so.*" - Shakespeare

Answer (score 2):

Neuroscience describes the bioelectromechanics of the brain in the same way science describes the workings of an automobile engine. Expecting that the blueprints of the engine will give an indication to its "true purpose" seems reasonable but an automobile engine can be used to propel boats, airplanes, etc. So while neuroscience can provide clues as to the brains function, it is limited in its ability to describe the purpose.

Comment: The purpose of a motor would be: to move something. "*Where do you want to go today?*" It is controlled by the nut that holds the steering wheel.

Comment: @ScottRowe A segment on the PBS show "This Old House" was "What does this do?" where they would bring out a strange tool and ask the experts to identify its purpose. It was fun to see how their minds worked since they were wrong more often then not. But it's a good reminder that reverse engineering alone may not be enough to determine purpose.

Comment: Lol. We've been poking at the brain for 100 years too, asking, "What does this part do?"

Answer (score 1):

Science favors the theory of evolution to explain the cause of our existence, and that cause means there is no objective purpose to our existence.

Psychological science can help detect subjective purposes to existence, meaning reasons to live that people have found or created. That would be a question for psychology, not philosophy though.

Philosophy knows the concept of ethical naturalistism, which would allow to sustain moral propositions with natural facts. It is (I believe) a minority view however, the is-ought-gap describes the majority view that it is a fallacy to derive what should be from what is. So it would be a fallacy to assume that our biology determinism morality or purpose.

In general, that's also safer, as some people find themselves with urges that are prone to harm others, and it's good to have some morality to protect those who would otherwise be harmed.

Comment: *"a question for psychology, not philosophy"* Aristotle's eudaimonia, the greatest good for the greatest number, confrontation with the absurd, awakening to the true nature of reality, & many other proposals *in philosophy* have been raised as purposes you can choose to direct your life around. You may disagree that any impel you personally. But surely you cannot claim they aren't philosophy.

Comment: There is no topic for which there won't be a community member pleading that this is philosophy. Philosophy is seen then like a supermarket of topics.  Still, the better answers are available where science has dug much deeper with experimental research than mere thought.

Comment: come on guys. Another discipline informing philosophy should be completely uncontroversial. It's happened countless times.

Comment: No one has answered my question to date. I assume no one is informed on the topic. Fair enough.

Comment: The unexamined definition is not worth having, I'd say. In this answer I make the case that rather than living well being a branch out from understanding the world, that understanding the world is only part of living well, of cultivating wisdom: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99784/where-is-the-line-between-semantics-and-ontology/99787#99787

Comment: I don't get the is-ought thing. Why don't we simply make what is better? It's just Engineering. Convert resource problems into technical ones and solve them. All the hand-wringing goes away with enough food, shelter, healthcare etc. You won't have to worry about morality if no one feels the need to harm others.

Answer (score 1):

You are presuming reductionism, where higher order things like morality, purpose, and consciousness, can be reduced to lower level things like neurons, or quarks.  The most famous explicit reductionist is Patricia Churchland, whose most recent relevant work is Braintrust:  [https://www.amazon.com/Braintrust-Neuroscience-Tells-about-Morality/dp/0691156344](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691156344) Churchland has done a lot of writing, and has inspired a lot of other authors, so there will be a large selection to dig into further of related works.

Another noteworthy reductionist is Daniel Dennett, whose latest major work is here:  [https://www.amazon.com/Bacteria-Bach-Back-Evolution-Minds/dp/0393242072](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393242072)  this book is not explicitly on how to live life, but Dennett is a polymath and will touch on it.  Dennett himself is a prolific writer, and if this work does not specifically address your interest, he has multiple other books that may.

However, global reductionism is now a small minority position in philosophy of science, although it remains the majority view among neurologists.  Most philosophers follow the sciences and consider sciences either their own independent truth systems (pluralism), OR to be emergent from and only dependent to a limited degree upon their substrates.  This includes the vast majority of physicalist philosophers.

For an emergence view, psychology would be EMERGENT FROM, not defined by neurology. And sociology would be EMERGENT FROM, not defined by psychology.  And morality would be EMERGENT FROM, not defined by sociology.  So, even for a physicalist who accepts emergence, neurology would be nearly useless to try to figure out what we should do with our life, as that is a question so many tiers away, that neurology would give almost no insights.

And for a pure pluralist view, there would be no value whatsoever to what neurology might suggest about values and purposes.

So -- if one accepts non-reductionist thinking, goals and purposes have to be studied and understood as their own separate field/subject.

Comment: Right, it is like a computer: transistors, systems, operating system, Microsoft Word, your dissertation. Study transistors for all time, and you'll learn nothing about dissertations. This just seems so obvious as to not need agreement.