What happened to the science of wisdom?

"At one time philosophy was the central intellectual discipline, now it
is peripheral.  Few care about the ‘latest developments’ in
philosophy.  Some might say there are none: that philosophy doesn’t
develop, it just asks the same old questions over and over"


"Philosophy was originally the study of everything. Much of its remit
was theology and metaphysics. For an epoch, science was called
‘natural philosophy’. However, as science stole the bulk of
philosophy, philosophy has redefined itself – one could say withdrawn
– into a narrower spectrum. Its subjects today revolve around the
mind: What is consciousness? What is knowledge? What is language? What
is logic? What is ethics?"


"Philosophy, it seems, currently has three main avenues, which, though
clogged, it tries to flow through. One is academic philosophy, which
is, one gathers, largely mired in esoteric analysis or
self-referential in-house debates. Another might collectively be
called ‘street philosophy’. It wants to be some modern version of
ancient Greek marketplace philosophy, but the correspondence doesn’t
stick. The third realm is ‘hidden philosophy’, held non-publicly by
individuals whose intellect and values funnel out into practice and
postures seen and unseen"
https://philosophynow.org/issues/98/What_Is_The_Present_Nature_And_The_Future_Of_Philosophy

Hegel's philosophy inspired Marx and defined the history of the 20th century.
Do we know what significant particular philosopher inspired in the 21st century?

Osama Bin Laden.

'Philo' means love, so Philosophy is "the love of wisdom", it wasn't regarded as science. (probably still isn't)

@ScottRowe "love of wisdom" vs "cultural functional stupidity". What kind of role model could teach kids about 'wisdom' nowadays?

Carl Sagan was pretty wise, but he was last millennium. Here's a name: Yuval Noah Harari. I'm thinking we would have been better off without Marx.

Be careful what you wish for, Nietzsche and Spengler also inspired and it was not all wisdom. Post-truth did not come out of nowhere either. On the other hand, there was Orwell, Hannah Arendt, who helped Germany wash off fascism, Freud, Husserl, Rawls, the father of modern liberalism, feminist thinkers, etc. 21st century is still young, we do not know yet who will have comparable influence. But philosophy was never a science and science did happen, taking over the ‘latest developments’. Wisdom and unwisdom take longer to simmer.

Im reasonably persuaded that Marx would have been Marx with or without Hegel. I see Marx as essentially an emotional force without intelligence — People are suffering so much lets make a revolution!  Its way too late before people realize that the sufferings only increased with the revolution (@ScottRowe). Just to be clear I dont think capitalism is any better in the long run than communism

Peter Singer is a good example of a modern philosopher of the kind you & Philosophy Now seem to think is missing, helping give form to the Animal Liberation movwment with his book of the same name, & to what has become the Effective Altruism movement with his essay 'Famine, Affluence, and Morality'. His discipline now is bioethics rather than pure academic philosophy. On the decline of interest in wisdom: 'Wisdom and John Vervaeke's awakening from the meaning crises?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82325/wisdom-and-john-vervaekes-awakening-from-the-meaning-crises/82333#82333

@Rushi: You say that like an emergent economic system is equivalent to an ideology. The comparison should be with John Locke & Adam Smith, who advocated for free markets & liberalism, &. Montesquieu & Voltaire who advocated for seperation of powers, & of church & state. These underpinned the US & French Revolutions, & define our modern politics.

You make it out as though philosophers used to deal in wisdom and this has stopped recently.
Real philosophy has always happened "by mistake" (Of course exceptions prove the rule).
In Hellenic times the word for philosophy was "sophism" and philosophers  were called "sophists".
Socrates didn't like their modus operandi so he added 'philos' to 'sophos' as a sign that head and heart need to go together.
I suppose you know what 'blessings' he received for doing philosophy.
And this feature remains as the most central theme of the most important western philosopher (assuming western makes any sense):

Plato: The good is higher than the true; but since the good has no being we (philosophers) talk of the true

Spinoza was banned and excommunicated.
Descartes (who I admittedly dont like as a philosopher; though coordinate geometry is beautiful) was exiled.
Schopenhauer was ignored.
Nietzsche went mad. Also, presciently his most quoted and misunderstood
line — God is dead — from his most cited work, Zarathustra, is in the mouth of a 'madman'.
William of Ockham was so true to his principle of parsimony
that he suggested that the Pope should have no property — basic Christianity101! As a result he had to run for his life.
In one of the more wise lines of Wittgenstein's closest fans, they admit He is not one of us.
It may be worthwhile to stop and consider the gap between what shaped and made Wittgenstein with what 99% of philosophers fashionably associate with him. This is why I say philosophy always happens "by mistake."
The only significant exception I can think of who was an official academic and a great philosopher was Kant — exception to the rule?
Coming back to Socrates: He said They are sophists; that's ok but not enough (for me). So I am a philo-sophist
You can be sure the sophists continue to do their sophistry; they've just learnt to call themselves "philo-sophists"
In short, you're unlikely to find wisdom if you search for it with the official "philosophers". That doesn't mean there was no wisdom in twentieth century (the 21st is still too young).
Twentieth Century
Some notable contemporary names that come to mind that may be termed both wise and philosophical

Arnold Toynbee – historian
Carl Jung – psychologist
Jean-Paul Sartre – author
Carl Sagan – scientist
Roger Penrose – physicist
Robert Rosen – biologist
Gödel – logician
Einstein – of course!
Rupert Sheldrake – maverick scientist
Noam Chomsky – linguist
Benjamin Lee Whorf – Linguist
Marshall McLuhan – media
Hannah Arendt – journalist
Jean Baudrillard – sociologist
David Bloor – sociologist
Roland Barthes – critic
Edward Said – Palestinian activist
Vijay Prashad – Indian activist
Vine Deloria – native American activist
Eckhart Tolle – spiritual teacher
Robert Spira  – non dual teacher
Alfred Korzybski – "independent scholar"
Dalai Lama – I'm not sure what to put here!


Noticing your title — science of wisdom — I add my own teacher, the physicist Ravi Ravindra, whose books are discipline-spanning like Science and the Sacred and culture-spanning like The Yoga of the Christ

"You make it out as though philosophers used to deal in wisdom and this has stopped recently." - In the quotes they are talking about lack of influence and breakthroughs. For me, it reminds religious studies. They just repeat the same texts over and over, trying to achieve wisdom by chanting.

Philosophy has merely evolved. The professional discipline we now know as philosophy is not the whole of philosophy. Philosophy was the pursuit of understanding. Many of those understandings have built their own homes - like physics,math,english lit, art and theology - the list goes on.
One way of noting this is a PhD stands for doctor of philosophy.

PhD means you are supposed to know more than just information about a subject, you are supposed to be wise. (and love the subject)

@Scott Rowe: I don't think PhD holders are necessarily wise. Todays world precludes it. Instead, they know a great deal about a small fragment of the whole. Simon Weil complained about how these virtuoso's of thought were helpless outside their narrow tower of specialisation. Actually, this is part of pop culture in describing them as nerds or geeks. Not originally a term of approbation.

We develop our knowledge until we reach an impasse. Like Ecclesiastes said.

@Scott Rowe: The point of obstructions is to learn how to get past them - this is how knowledge develops. Otherwise we'll always be stuck at an impasse ...

@Scott Rowe: Can you show me where Ecclesiastes said what you said he did?

Ecclesiastes 1:18 "With much wisdom comes much vexation, and he who increases knowledge increases sorrow."

@Scott Rowe: That has nothing to do with "we develop our knowledge until we reach an impasse". But simply, for the first, the more you know, the more you can see what is wrong with the world and are vexed in not being able to fix it and hence, gor the second sentence, increase ones sorrow.
